# regex question for trimming the white space for validating name input

Tags: javascript, regex

Check if the value for name entered contains first name and last name with a space between. I use the following regex but face problem when there is a trailing space, it returns false. 
How do I ignore the trailing space in my regex?

```
var nameArr = value.match(/^([^ ]{1,50})[, ]+(.{0,49}[^ ,])$/);
```

My approach for resolving the trailing space
var nameArr = value.trim().match(/^([^ ]{1,50})[, ]+(.{0,49}[^ ,])$/);
Is there other way besides using trim method?

Comment: The way you use comma in `[, ]+` is it correct? `john,,,,,doe` appears to be a valid name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\s*` to match zero or more whitespaces. Use that at the end and at the beginning of your regexp to allow for leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
var nameArr = value.match(/^\s*([^ ]{1,50})[, ]+(.{0,49}[^ ,])\s*$/);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get trimmed match for "firstName lastName" or "firstName,lastName" in matched object, use this:

```
var nameArr=value.match(/(?=\s*)(\w{1,50})[, ](\w{1,50})(?=\s*)/);
```

You used [, ]+ in your regex,if you aimed to match for "first, last" case(presence of both ',' and ' ') use this:

```
var nameArr=value.match(/(?=\s*)\w{1,50}(,\s|[,\s])\w{1,50}(?=\s*)/);
```

(?= pattern) are called lookaheads , they look for specified pattern without matching them , i.e. pattern should be there to pass the test but it won't show up in matched object.Thus giving us trimmed Name.